# HL7 database setup and android client to store patient info in hl7 format

Tags: android, hl7, hapi

I am very new to clinical system development. We are having one android application which store some patient information locally. Now we want to store this info to HL7 system.
Here what I want to know at first level:-

1) I know some what about HAPI which provide api to generate HL7 messages, is it correct?
Like can we use it with android or is there any other java library?

2) We want to setup HL7 data base and service at our end on which my android app can store data remotely.
So for this as per my basic search I found openEMR , mirth.. so can any one please give more info for this kind of setup. And suggest proper way to do it.

Thank you in advance. :)

Regards,
Ankit

Comment: Hi @Ankit, I am developer in a similar situation as you and have looked into the tools you describe here (HAPI and Mirth Connect). I do not have answers for you, as I am not done with my implementation yet. You don't mention which HL7 format you need to support. Keep in mind HAPI supports HL7 2.x only. You can use Mirth Connect as an interface engine and use it to convert data from a simple format you define and to HL7 (both 2.x and 3.x).  I'll be following this question, and I hope more experienced developers in clinical systems will give their input. Good luck with your development efforts!

Comment: Also as an additional comment, you keep in mind security issues before you store patient information locally on the Android device.

Comment: Hi @Leffy, Thank you very much for your response,Ya I will keep in mind security issue, as our application also going to be used in US. So i think security should be main consideration also.Okay So now I will do more research on Mirth connect and first try to setup all thing locally. And I will also update once I got any positive way to full fill my need. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Leffy, I have started with HAPI as of now, But we are getting trouble during conversion of HL7 message to XML using HAPI inside methods. During Android build, added HAPI java libs(jars) and other its dependency jar creating problem. Giving dex error while creation of its .dex files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would post this as a comment rather than the answer, but it seems I don’t have such capability (no “add comment” button). My comment would be that you need to refine your question a bit since there are no such things as HL7 systems and HL7 database. The HL7 standard is a vehicle to communicate medical data, it does not govern (and it should not) how systems handle and store these data. Similarly as POP3/SMTP protocols do not govern how to build an email client and store emails. Furthermore, it is not feasible to use the HL7 RIM as a database structure pattern, you will end up de-normalizing it a lot (Abdul-Malik Shakir did a presentation about it).

What it means is that you are free to use any database and DB structure for your application; same is true for the remote system. This may answer your second question.

Next thing to do is to find out what exact messages you need to support in order to exchange medical data. It might happen that all you need to do is to request/update patient demographics. Or request and present a CDA report. In such case you may build your own custom library and support only a small subset of segments (for HL7v2) or messages (for v3). The trade off of such solution is that it is not easily scalable.

Ps. If possible, move this to comments.

Comment: Thank You very much. Its okay, No need to move to comments as it is one of good answer for me :)

Comment: And ya like as of now we are doing something same. Using OpenMrs database model to store data of patient as per their table. And like finally we are going with OpenMrs system to view those data.(using its web interface), Like android app call one web service/open mars web services to send Patient required data and then those we can view on OpenMrs web interface(web application). And its like almost right direction for us.